# IExecutorService's main motive?

Tags: threadpool, hazelcast

I know about high availability and scalability (etc) advantages of Hazelcast. But i just want to ask about main motive of distributed executor service and i have some questions in my mind. kindly just answer the following questions

---

If client load on the server is only in the form of blocking I/O requests(Data base queries etc) then is there a need to use IExecutorService or ThreadPoolExecutor is enough for this scenario?

If client load on the server is only in the form of CPU-intensive requests but request rate is high then IExecutorService can serve this scenario better on cluster, is this statement true?

The main motive of IExecutorService is to handle CPU-intensive request's load on the cluster by horizontal scaling.Is this statement true?

Answer (score 0):

- If client load on the server is only in the form of blocking I/O requests(Data base queries etc) then is there a need to use IExecutorService or ThreadPoolExecutor is enough for this scenario?

It depends. It doesn't only need to be CPU intensive tasks. For example if each tasks requires doing a lot of IO, but this resource is scalable, e.g.:
- the local file system of a member machine, 
- another cluster (maybe there is a big Cassandra cluster) that stores data
it could still be a good use-case for HZ.

If you are using HZ to scale up doing remote calls to a db, it could very well that you bring the database to it knees :)

- If client load on the server is only in the form of CPU-intensive requests but request rate is high then IExecutorService can serve this scenario better on cluster, is this statement true?

It depends. You pay a price for the PRC, so if you have very small tasks, it could very well be that the IExecutorService is not your friend. For similar reasons it could be that the Executor is not your friend, because there could be a huge contention on the work-queue of the executor.

So it depends on the type of task being processed if it makes sense to use the IExecutorService or even an Executor.

- The main motive of IExecutorService is to handle CPU-intensive request's load on the cluster by horizontal scaling.Is this statement true?

See answer #1

There are not absolute answers to your questions. It very depends on a lot of factors.